# how to save xml file in locally in blackberry?

Tags: xml, blackberry

I want to take xml from internet, but everytime taking xml from net makes slow to my application, so i am thinking to take and save in local directory and next time i open app then at back end the xml again copied from internet to my xml

how to do that, and is there any other good way to solve this problem?

Comment: isnt there an app folder ? is usage of xml mandatory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please the use the following function to write the file to SD card.

```
    private  static String APP_DOC_DIR =  "file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/documents/MyAPP/";

public static void writeToSD(String fileName, String fileContent){
    FileConnection fconn = null;
        // APP_DOC_DIR is the directory name constant.
    try {
         FileConnection fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open(APP_DOC_DIR);
     // If no exception is thrown, the URI is valid but the folder may not exist.
     if (!fc.exists())
     {
         fc.mkdir();  // create the folder if it doesn't exist
     }
     fc.close();


        fconn = (FileConnection) Connector.open(APP_DOC_DIR + fileName ,Connector.READ_WRITE);          
        if (!fconn.exists()) {
            fconn.create();
        }
        fconn.setReadable(true);
        fconn.setWritable(true);
        OutputStream os = fconn.openOutputStream();
        os.write(fileContent.getBytes("UTF8"));
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fconn!=null) {
            try {
                fconn.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Read file from SD Card is follows.

```
public static String readFromSD(String fileName)
    {
        String resultString = "";
        int BUFFER_SIZE = 10000;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        FileConnection fconn;
        try {
            fconn = (FileConnection) Connector.open( APP_DOC_DIR + fileName, Connector.READ);
            if (fconn.exists()) 
            {
                inputStream = fconn.openInputStream();
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while (true) {
                int bytesRead = inputStream.read( buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE );
                if (bytesRead == -1)
                        break;
                byteArrayOutputStream.write( buffer, 0, bytesRead );
            }
            byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
            byte[] result = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            byteArrayOutputStream.close();
            //resultString = new String(result,"UTF8");
            resultString = new String(result);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultString;
    }
```

Comment: Yet I didnt test it, but atleast sure k some dared to think and answer, thank you sir...